# Can't find the Performance Explorer in my VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance, testing, performance-testing

Hi do i need to install something to get the [Performance Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualizeparallel/archive/2010/06/01/becoming-a-performance-explorer.aspx)?

because i doesn't have any of the Menupoints where i can open this Tool, so please tell me what i miss.

**Version:**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709 SP1Rel

Installierte Version: Professional

 - Microsoft Office Developer Tools   01018-587-3079896-70636 Microsoft
 - Visual Basic 2010   01018-587-3079896-70636 Microsoft Visual C# 2010 
 - 01018-587-3079896-70636 Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  
 - 01018-587-3079896-70636 Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer  
 - 01018-587-3079896-70636 Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010  
 - 01018-587-3079896-70636 Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft
 - Visual Studio 2010
```

### Here is how my VS 2010 current looks

[image: How it current looks]

### Here is how it should looks like

[image]

Comment: Is the option View -> Other Windows -> Performance Explorer missing for you?

Comment: @Malice this is missing as well (i will add some images)

Comment: @Malice ok please see my Edit. Does my Professional doesn't support this stuff ??

Comment: My screen looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iyWAY.png which suggests that maybe VS2010 Professional doesn't support it. I am using VS2010 Premium.

Comment: @Malice  on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc470664.aspx) i can read "Visual Studio Ultimate, Visual Studio Premium, **Visual Studio Professional**" for VS 2012 if i now swap to older version i'm not able to find anything about the requirement

Comment: Yes, I found that page earlier. I didn't want to link it because it doesn't state whether VS2010 Premium supports Performance Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, profiling tools (of which the performance explorer is part of) are shipped with Premium and Ultimate versions only.

**edit**: I really should have mentioned that I was talking about the 2010 editions of VS. My mistake.

Comment: Visual Studio Ultimate, Visual Studio Premium, **Visual Studio Professional**  [here is the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc470664.aspx) for VS 2012 if  than look at older version i can't see anything about which version it required